# Why is "gusting" not the opposite of "disgusting"?

Tags: negation, antonyms, prefixes

The prefix **dis** often makes a word negative. It is a negative prefix. For example: courage and **dis**courage, the latter is the opposite of the former. Continue and **dis**continue, honest and **dis**honest and many more.

But *gusting* and *disgusting* are not opposites?? Why is this so? I can't think of any other words that show the same behavior. Is there any reason why both of them are not opposites?

Comment: Perhaps they invented the word 'disgust' prior to inventing 'gust'. (This is a very casual comment, not an answer, not even slightly inclined.)

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Maybe. It would be awesome if you could explain it in an answer ;-)

Comment: Oh no, I don't know the correct etymologies and I don't want to put you off the track. Hence I added the words 'casual'. I am sure someone knowing the concepts in depth can answer it. I will definitely look forward to this post.

Comment: **A point to note:** 'disgust' is a verb. However, 'disgusting' is an adjective, and 'gusting' is a verb. Two complete different parts of speech altogether. The antonyms usually always belong to the same part of speech. Like: _continue_ and _discontinue_, _honest_ and _dishonest_, etc.

Comment: This is a long story of etymology and linguistic history, maybe more appropriate for english.stackexchange than for ell.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Maybe, but I am more comfortable here than english.stackexchange. Questions there require more research and effort and people like me who can't do research on such things feel bad to bear their "harsh" comments (actually I deleted my previous account on that site a long time ago due to their harshness, but due to my enthusiasm in English, I made another). I also ask deep etymological and linguistic questions there but with much effort and research as much as I can do.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that the word **disgust** was imported into English from French with the prefix already attached, but the word without a prefix was not also imported.

Longer answer:

If you look at the etymology of the word [**disgust**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/disgust), you'll see that it comes from the 16th-century Middle French word *desgouster*, which was formed from *des-* (a negative prefix) and *gouster* (to have a taste for).  By some accident of history, only *desgouster* was adopted into Middle English and eventually the modern English **disgust**, though you can see evidence of *gouster* in the rarely-used word [**gustatory**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gustatory).

Both of these words continue to exist in modern French, with the letter 's' being turned into diacritics: *goûter* means "to taste" or "to like the taste of"; *dégoûter* means "to dislike the taste of".

So why wasn't *gouster* also imported into English?  Again, it's probably just an accident, but there are two possible contributing factors:

1. As @rjpond notes, the word [**gust**](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=gust) already existed as a Norse import having a completely unrelated meaning.
2. There's another Middle French word, *taster*, that originally meant "to touch or sample" that was imported into Middle English. Since then, it has evolved differently in each modern language: in modern English, **taste** exclusively means "to sample by mouth", but in modern French, *tâter* exclusively means "to sample by touch" or "to feel out". So the modern English "to taste" now means the same thing as the modern French "goûter".

Comment: This is very interesting! (I also found another pair: "appointed" and "disappointed".)

Comment: They're called [unpaired words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unpaired_word) (also see [this article](https://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/unpaired.htm)).

Comment: @Void I am [gruntled](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disgruntled) by your knowing a technical term for this.

Answer (score 1):

"Gust" means a rush of wind and is from Norse "gustr".  This gives us the verb "gust" meaning "to blow in gusts".

"Gust" is also a dialect word meaning "taste" (from Latin "gustus") or "to taste" (Latin "gustare").  There is an archaic word "gustful" meaning tasty or pleasant, and Scottish "gusty" meaning tasty or appetising.

"Disgust" was borrowed from French, not formed directly from dis + gust.

Comment: Oh, it actually makes a lot of sense.